# FullCalendar buscar dados à base de dados php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

Estou a gerar um calendário para um site, e sou obrigado a usar a ferramenta [fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). A questão é ir buscar os eventos por php à minha base de dados. Em js, os dados são listados no seguinte ficheiro demo.calendar.js e contem o seguinte:

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Full Calendar
        if( $.fn.fullCalendar ) {

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $("#mws-calendar").fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                events: [{
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                }, {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                }, {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                }]
            });
        }
    });

}) (jQuery, window, document);
```

Agora tenho uma questão, há alguma maneira de ir buscar os eventos por php? Ou meter este código num ficheiro php? ou no header?

Estou a fazer: retornar o valor por jason, mas até agora sem qualquer sucesso.

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Full Calendar
        if( $.fn.fullCalendar ) {

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $("#mws-calendar").fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                events: './myfeed.php'
            });
        }
    });

}) (jQuery, window, document);
```

e no ficheiro myfeed.php tenho o seguinte (é um exemplo sem a consulta à BD ainda, bastava-me aparecer os eventos em baixo, que a consulta para já não é precisa):

```
<?php

   $year = date('Y'); 
   $month = date('m');

   echo json_encode(array( 

      array( 
         'id' => 1, 
         'title' => "Event1", 
         'start' => "$year-$month-20", 
         'end' => "$year-$month-22", 
         'url' => "http://google.com/" 
      ), 

      array( 
         'id' => 2, 
         'title' => "Event2", 
         'start' => "$year-$month-20", 
         'end' => "$year-$month-22", 
         'url' => "http://yahoo.com/" 
      ) 

   ));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer desta forma:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "myfeed.php",
data: {       //the data    },
success: function(events)
  {
          $('#mws-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
          $('#mws-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);         
          $('#mws-calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );
   }
 });
```

Verifique também se o arquivo myfeed.php esta na mesma pasta do arquivo js

Comment: mas apago tudo o que está no demo.calendar.php e meto isso? sim, o myfeed.php está na mesma página. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: no lugar do if depois do ready

Comment: assim o calendário deixa de aparecer

Comment: no seu antigo codigo, aparece algum erro no terminal? execute o calendario com o inspecionador de elementos apertando F12, vai na aba network, e analise se ta sendo consultada o arquivo myfeed.php, se tiver, abra a requisição e analise o headers e response. Cole aqui se possível.